# Widevine can only run on ARMv7

Tags: ios, ooyala

When i am trying to `run a video` with `embedded ID` in the `OOyala player`, i am getting like `"Widevine can only run on ARMv7"`.

```
NSLog(@"video id= %@ ",videoID);
self.ooyalaPlayerViewController = [[OOOoyalaPlayerViewController alloc] initWithPcode:PCODE domain:PLAYERDOMAIN];

// Attach it to current view
[self addChildViewController:_ooyalaPlayerViewController];
[self.ooyalaPlayerViewController.view setFrame:self.videoPlayerView.bounds];
[self addChildViewController:self.ooyalaPlayerViewController];
[self.videoPlayerView addSubview:self.ooyalaPlayerViewController.view];

// Load the video
[self.ooyalaPlayerViewController.player setEmbedCode:videoID];

// Add observers
[self addObserversForOoyalaVideoplayer];

[self addCloseButton];

[self.ooyalaPlayerViewController.player play];
```

Comment: What device are you using ?

Comment: Now i am running in a simulator...ipad
and i have added the armv7 architecture in BuildSettings

Answer (score 1):

I added that line a while back when I still worked at Ooyala.

Basically, the Widevine playback library for iOS is only distributed in compiled ARM binaries.  The simulator runs natively on x86, so it can't load the library (I believe is purposeful, as it makes the DRM code slightly harder to reverse engineer), and we issue a warning.

Try playing it back on an actual device and everything should work fine.

Comment: Also, the warning is a little out of date- I believe Widevine also added support for armv7s

Comment: @chrisl I am getting this issue when running on iPhone 5S. Any thoughts? (We are disabling the 64-bit support anyway).

Comment: as Mazyod Said i have the problem in iphone 5s :(

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we were testing on the iPhone 5S, which can't really be ignored.

As it turns out, the issue was that we left the project files configurations as they are, which added arm64 support to the build, and that broke the player. All we had to do was override the architecture configuration in all the project files and build.

Answer (score 0):

Set valid and build architectures in the build settings to armv7 and try to run the application it will work.